# Изменение настроек мастер звука в Windows

Tags: c#, аудио

Мне нужно программно выключать и включать левый канал мастер микшера *Windows* (так сказать все программы теперь будут играть только на правый динамик).

Но так как я с *WinAPI* не дружу, я бы хотел найти библиотеку или готовый класс на *C#* (вот с ним я дружу) с готовым инкапсулированным функционалом, по типу назначения уровня баланса, настроек эффектов и прочее. То есть, всё что можно настроить в звуке микшера *Windows*.

Надеюсь, такое есть.

Comment: @Ep1demic, используйте, пожалуйста, пустую строку вместо `<br>` для выделения абзацев.

Comment: NAudio смотрели? доступен в Nuget